# Does it make sense to replace Interfaces/Pure Abstract Classes with Concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20

As I have understood are concepts quite similar to interfaces: Like interfaces, concepts allow to define some kind of a set of methods/concept/interface, which the implementation expects and needs to perform its task. Both strengthen the focus on semantic needs.

While Bjarne and many other people seem to see concepts as way to get rid of uses of enable_if and generally complicated templates, I wonder if it makes sense to use it instead of interfaces/pure abstract classes.

Benefits are obvious:

- no runtime cost (v-table)
- kind of duck typing, because the suitable classes do not have to implement the interface
- even relationships between parameters (which interfaces do not support at all)

Of course a disadvantage is not far away:

- no template definition checking for concepts, at least for now
- …

I wonder if there are more of these and if it would make no sense after all.

I know that there are similar questions, but they are not specific with their purpose nor is it answered in an answer. I also found other people who had the same idea, but at no point there is somebody who really encourages/discourages this, let alone argues on it.

Comment: "*no template definition checking for concepts, at least for now*" You can pretty much remove the "at least for now" qualifier: I guarantee you that definition checking is *never* going to happen in C++.

Comment: why are you so sure about that? (Ill get busy with your reply later, thanks for it)

Comment: "*why are you so sure about that?*" For one, [SG8 for Concepts is considered "dormant"](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee), meaning they have no active work. And if you're going to have definition checking for concepts, then the Concepts SG should probably be involved. Plus, there have been hundreds of proposals in the last year alone; *not one of them* was for this. None of them even talked about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using abstract classes *for their intended purpose*, then there is pretty much no way to replace them with concepts. Abstract base classes are for *runtime* polymorphism: the ability to, at runtime, have the implementation of an interface be decoupled from the site(s) where that interface gets used. You can use user input or data from a file to determine which derived class instance to create, then pass that instance to some other code that uses a pointer/reference to the base class.

Abstract classes are for defining an interface for runtime polymorphism.

A template is instantiated at compile-time. As such, everything about its interface must be verified at compile-time. You cannot vary which implementation of an interface you use for a template; it's statically written into your program, and the template gets instantiated with exactly and only the types you spell out in your code. That's compile-time polymorphism.

Concepts are for defining an interface for compile-time polymorphism. They don't work at runtime.

If you've been using abstract base classes for compile-time polymorphism, then you've been doing the wrong thing, and you should have stopped well before concepts came out.

Comment: thanks again for the answer - Indeed I use interfaces also for "possibly compile time " polymorphism. Simply because templating has quite a few drawbacks: no definition of interfaces(! respectively interfaces are at most defined implicitly by class internals, correct me if I am wrong), need of defining functions in the header, more difficult debugging... Of course there may be performance costs. So, back to the question: I did not think about the concepts of runtime/compile time polymorphism when I wrote the question.

Comment: Thus, I probably rather should ask if it makes sense, when compile time polymorphism is applicable.